# Show categories proportions in histogram with fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a histogram similar to this example:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
data <- structure(list(Group = c(23L, 18L, 23L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 2L, 19L, 2L, 19L, 2L, 19L, 18L, 3L, 19L), Weight = c(0.0111111111111111, 0.0111111111111111, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037, 0.0037037037037037), 
    Distance = c(187.499584053076, 187.499584053076, 10.6737766469012, 
    10.6737766469012, 281.336385978512, 281.336385978512, 253.13100905741, 
    253.13100905741, 251.437995888686, 251.437995888686, 237.356329723974, 
    237.356329723974, 250.386230871559, 250.386230871559, 368.035367705982, 
    368.035367705982, 356.508544839761, 356.508544839761, 469.363999574087, 
    469.363999574087)), .Names = c("Group", "Weight", "Distance"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

mdata = melt(data, id=c('Weight','Group'))

ggplot(mdata, aes(x=value, weight = Weight, fill=Group)) +
geom_bar(position="fill")
```

I can't seem to be able to tell ggplot to use `Group` as colours. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it a factor. Also `weight` is not a valid aesthetic mapping.

```
mdata$Group = factor(mdata$Group)
ggplot(mdata, aes(x=value, fill=Group)) +
    geom_bar(position="fill")
```